# Can't import matplotlib even if it's installad

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pip

I am running a sample python program on my Mac (El Capitan, 10.11.5)
I have a the default version of python installed (2.6) and on top of that I installed python 2.7 and 3.5.  I need matplotlib on my 2.7 version.

I installed it with pip (not pip3) and I don't know why it got installed on python 3.5.

If I type `pip list` this is the output:

```
cycler (0.10.0)
Django (1.8.4)
matplotlib (1.5.1)
numpy (1.11.1)
pip (8.1.2)
pyparsing (2.1.5)
python-dateutil (2.5.3)
pytz (2016.6.1)
selenium (2.53.6)
setuptools (19.4)
six (1.10.0)
wheel (0.26.0)
```

`which python` outputs: `/usr/local/bin/python`

My path is:

```
/usr/local/share/python3:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

In `/usr/local/share/python3`: I have python 3.5, in `/usr/local/bin`: python 2.7 and then in `/usr/bin` the default python.

When I run in my program `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` and try to use it I get:

> ImportError: No module named matplotlib

I think the problem is that matplotlib is installed on python3.5 site-package. How could I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: please check `python -m site`, I guess  the `python` binary runs from a different environment than pip has you believe.

Comment: You could `ls` into the python site-packages to be sure exactly where it's installed

Comment: To further add up on what @miraculixx said, using `pip --version` will not only tell you the Pip version but also for which python install it is configured.

Comment: And a *which pip* tells you where it was found too.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a the default version of python installed (2.6) and on top of that I installed python 2.7 and 3.5. I need matplotlib on my 2.7 version.

that's genereally not a problem, however you need to make sure the python environments are not mixed up.

> I think the problem is that matplotlib is installed on python3.5 site-package. How could I fix this?

**1. Use python's virtualenv feature**

My recommendation is to use [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) *):

```
# for a python 3.5 environment
$ cd /path/to/<project with python 3>
$ PATH="/path/to/python3.x;$PATH" python -m venv myenv

# for a python 2.7 environment
$ cd /path/to/<project with python 2>
$ PATH="/path/to/python2.7;$PATH" virtualenv myenv
```

This will create clean per-project python environments with their seperate `site-packages`. With that you can work on your project (or even multiple projects) that have different packages or package versions installed, without them interfering.

*That said, before you move any further, open a new Terminal to make sure all path are reset to a clean state.*

**2. Re-Install packages into your fresh virtualenv**

Activate the environment and re-install the required packages into the project's environment using

```
# assuming the list of packages is in /path/to/project/requirements.txt
$ cd /path/to/project
$ source myenv/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Once you have done this, you should be able to import matplotlib lib just fine:

```
python -c 'import matplotlib; print matplotlib'
<module 'matplotlib' from '/path/to/python/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc'>
```

**3. Give yourself a break**

To simplify using virtualenvs try [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). This adds a couple of commands to your system to simplify the handling of virtualenvs, e.g.:

```
# create new environments
$ mkvirtualenv foo
# activate a particular environment
$ workon foo
# list packages in your environment 
$ lssitepackages 
(...)
```

*) Note that Python 3 provides the [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) package as part of the standard library, whereas Python 2.7 requires that you install the `virtualenv` package first.